# Могут ли вопросы быть глупыми?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, голоса-против

Иногда, бродя по русскоязычному SO, встречаю вопросы, необоснованно заминусованные.

Хочет человек спросить что-то нетривиальное, его тут же закидывают минусами, и внушают ему, что он хочет спросить совсем о другом.
Тут он испытывает колоссальное давление, и либо остаётся на SO, отстаивая свою точку зрения, попутно получая ещё больше минусов, либо просто напросто уходит с SO. Почти так было и со мной…

Сейчас я хотел бы:

1. Услышать ваш ответ на вопрос "Могут ли вопросы быть глупыми?"
2. Понять, почему мне накидали столько палок за следующие вопросы:

   1) [Evaluate Android Studio текстовой переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568480/evaluate-android-studio-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

   2) [составить регулярное выражение для C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587429/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-c)

Comment: Вопросы не "глупые", они низкого качества, за это и заминусили.

Comment: Имхо, в обоих случаях вы спрашиваете, как делать что-то плохое. Хороший ответ на это объяснял бы, почему так делать не надо и как сделать лучше. Выполнять код из строки — потенциальная дыра в безопасности. Разбирать HTML регулярками — плохо, неэффективно, есть специальные парсеры HTML для этой задачи.

Comment: Конечно, лучше подробно ответить на такой вопрос, чем минус ставить.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Конечно могут быть. Почему нет?

Вопрос в том, как в этому относиться. Тут уже не раз эта тема поднималась.

Касательно же ваших вопросов:

1. Тут пара моментов:

   1. Если отвечающий не работал с js/php и т.п языками, где есть `eval`, то ему сначала нужно будет загуглить, что это за зверь.
   2. Ироничный тон "Уверен, здесь есть знающие ребята".
   3. Не расписано, что именно вы хотите и какими средствами:

      1. Чисто нативно?
      2. Свой парсер?
      3. Вызывать сторонний интерпретатор?
2. Тоже самое.

   1. Типичное "Дано это, хочу это, сделайте". Многие на это агрятся и расценивают как домашку, а потом минусуют/закрывают. Чтоб этого избежать, желательно написать, какие попытки в написании регулярки вы делали, что именно не получается. Если вы не умеете писать регулярки вовсе, а просто ищете готовое решение, то это вдвойне плохо.
   2. Нет конкретики/контекста. Регулярки для разбора html - плохо. А в тексте вы не указали, хотите парсить всю страницу или нужно распарсить небольшую строку. От этого ответ может сильно отличаться.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Уточнил свои запросы. Стоит ли ещё что-то изменить в них?

Comment: Уже лучше. Но, если вы хотите совета по тому, как улучшить вопросы, то наверно стоит в чате это спрашивать, а не на мете )

Answer (score 11):

Знаете, вы задали интересный вопрос, он типичен для многих людей, кто начинает "свой путь" юзания SO. Как ни странно, а я до сих пор помню, как я в первый раз задал свой вопрос и наловил уйму минусов... )))
Какой-то момент, я был в замешательстве и не понимал как это так, что я мол пришел на форум, задал вроде-бы не тупой вопрос, а тут гора минусов... Не порядок...  )))
Вот тогда я и задался своим первым вопросом (Как так получается, что одни получают кучу плюсов, а я пролетерий - т.е. человек, который пролетает мимо...?).
Тут не просто так написана [*справка*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), там выложен, достаточный объем информации для человека, который хочет начать пользоваться ресурсом и получать от него для себя лично или для других целей, какие-то дивиденды, но многие её игнорят, несмотря на то, что в комментариях им постоянно про это пишут, и дают прямую ссылку где почитать.

*Думаю, я ответил на ваш первый вопрос:*

> Услышать ваш ответ на вопрос "Могут ли вопросы быть глупыми?"

К написаному выше добавлю, да!
Конечно, но это не значит, что человек в чем-то не прав или-же он глуп, скорее уровень его компетентности на данный момент просто ниже и ничего страшного в этом нет. Просто надо продолжать двигаться, не опускать руки и прибавлять с каждым разом. Стараться улучшать свои вопросы раз за разом, подчитывая дополнительную информацию и выполняя определенную работу над собой.

*Ответ на ваш второй вопрос:*

> Понять, почему мне накидали столько палок за следующие вопросы:
>
> 1) Evaluate Android Studio текстовой переменной
>
> 2) составить регулярное выражение для C#

любезно предоставил @Suvitruf, с моей колокольни добавить нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотрите, вас же никто не заставляет отвечать человеку с очень простым вопросом, найдутся люди которым не трудно дать банальное решение на его вопрос! Зачем ставить минус, просто так! Руки чешутся? Можно же просто проигнорить и пойти дальше.

Stackoverflow.com - это самое крупное онлайн-сообщество для программистов, чтобы учиться, делиться своими знаниями и строить свою карьеру.

И исходя из этого можно сказать, когда они задают глупые вопросы, они учатся, и мы в роли учителя должны направить их, а не выгнать из класса)))

И кстати задавая такие вопросы, возможно даже похожие вопросы уже были на сайте, данная страница начнет продвигаться SEO, так как текст все равно будет уникальным. Тем самым увеличивая посещения сайта stackoverflow.com, а это плюс)

Comment: в самих минусах нет ничего плохого, это всего лишь отношение к вопросу/ ответу, и относиться к этому надо соответственно. а вот если вопрос собрал *пачку* минусов, то скорее всего проблема есть, и если т.с. не может определить её сам, то в этом случае можно попросить  прокомментировать причину минусования: под вопросом/ответом, в чате, на мете

Comment: просто сами понимаете люди злые, и могут зайти, не понравился вопрос минусанули и ушли, и так у задавшего вопрос может оказаться и -5 и -10. Ну в основном минусуют то новичков, в плане которые даже не знают про мету) Я смотрю даже мне уже влепили минус) критика всегда не приветствуется, правда глаза режет!

Comment: за то время, пока я *участвую* в сообществе, ни разу не было *пачки* минусов на простых вопросах,  да и есть участники которые комментируют свои минуса. *не знание закона...* справку же надо читать :)